# Does the Spell check component works with EdisMax queries?

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, spell-checking, edismax

What happens if I use the solr spell checker component on the `/select` handler, and when making a query I use edisMax? I'm particulary interested in the `_query_` 'magic field'.

Example: `q=Helikopter"_query_:"{!edismax qs=2 pf='' qf='test^1 test_2^1 v=$q0}"`

My question is: would spell checker component be able to make suggest on this query?

Like suggest `Helicopter`